# Upload large files on RoR

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a project in Ruby on Rails 4, which as the main requirement is to upload large files between 400MB and 1.5GB, everything depends on the information containing those files, however, are currently seeking alternatives in relation to upload those files where the application kept uploading files while the user is doing any other tasks (filling a new form where also will load a new file).

We are using the API of Google Drive (where the files will store) and `gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"`.

Based on your experience, how can i do or where can I find information for this requirement or any advise will be helpful.

Example on page 3 of this [pdf](https://bitbucket-assetroot.s3.amazonaws.com/perkhand/id-diagnostica/1442240828.93/15/consulta%20form.pdf?Signature=1sk2oaWtC2x0slm8ITWlYD7YdhY%3D&Expires=1443012153&AWSAccessKeyId=0EMWEFSGA12Z1HF1TZ82)

Thank you in advances

Comment: Link to pdf file is expired...

Comment: @PavelTkackenko try now

Comment: Expired again. Post a link without TTL.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I had the same problem, so, if it can help :

Jquery-fileupload has an option for chunked upload (upload multiple tiny files rather than one big file)
Try with :

`$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    maxChunkSize: 1000000,
    maxFileSize: 1000000 * 10000,`

It works really well for large file upload.